# How to resize children inside a dialog, when dialog is resized

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a composite in a dialog.
I want to resize the dialog and when the dialog is resizing i want to update the composite accordingly.

How do I set the resizing of the composite also?

Below is my code snippet :

```
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
final GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
container.setLayout(gridLayout);

final Composite composite = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
final GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, false, 
                                                                 false);
gridData.heightHint = 300;
gridData.widthHint = 600;
composite.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

I have a TableViewer inside this Composite.

Please let me know how to handle this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to call `setLayout` on **every** `Composite` you create.

If you use `GridLayout` for the layout of a composite use `GridData` which specifies `SWT.FILL` and 'grab extra space`:

```
 control.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
```

will make the control use all the horizontal space.

```
 control.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

will make the control take all available space in both directions.

Note: You must create a new `GridData` for each control - **do not** try to share them between controls (the same applies to layouts).

To make a dialog resizeable in the first place override `isResizable`:

```
@Override
protected boolean isResizable()
{
  return true;
}
```